# How to display a query in a certain way?

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm currently new to queries and below I have a query that I have made 
QUERY:

```
select TITLE_ID, TITLE,NAME, JOB_CATEGORY AS ROLE
FROM MOVIES
NATURAL JOIN NEW_NAMES
WHERE JOB_CATEGORY = 'writer'
OR JOB_CATEGORY = 'director'
ORDER BY TITLE_ID ASC;
```

Which Displays:

```
TITLE_ID | TITLE | NAME | ROLE    |
753595   | 2F2F  | ROB  | WRITER  |
753595   | 2F2F  | YAS  | DIRECTOR|
```

However I would like it to display in this format below:

```
TITLE_ID | TITLE | WRITER | DIRECTOR|
753595   | 2F2F  | ROB    | YAS     |
```

Answer (score 0):

You join your `NEW_NAMES` table in twice. Once for director, once for `writer`. When you join a table more than once it's necessary that you give the table an Alias, here we use `writer` and `director`.

```
select TITLE_ID, TITLE,writer.NAME as writer_name, director.NAME as director_name
FROM MOVIES
LEFT OUTER JOIN NEW_NAMES as writer
     ON MOVIES.TITLE_ID = writer.TITLE_ID
     AND  writer.JOB_CATEGORY = 'writer'
LEFT OUTER JOIN NEW_NAMES as director
     ON MOVIES.TITLE_ID = director.TITLE_ID
     AND director.JOB_CATEGORY = 'director'    
ORDER BY TITLE_ID ASC;
```

I've made some assumptions in those `ON` clauses about which columns in your tables you are joining on. You may need to edit that.

Comment: Hmm I see where your coming from, but this code did not work. So I will try a left outer join and see if that gets the outcome I want.  This was the error:                                               ```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

```

Comment: This code below does what I need but it doesn't separate the writer or director in its own column                                                                                                                       
`select TITLE_ID, TITLE,NAME AS "WRITER OR DIRECTOR"
FROM MOVIES
NATURAL JOIN NEW_NAMES
WHERE JOB_CATEGORY = 'writer'
OR JOB_CATEGORY = 'director'
ORDER BY TITLE_ID ASC;`

Comment: I've rewritten using a LEFT OUTER JOIN. An `ON` clause was added for each join and made the assumption that the tables are joined on `title_id`. I moved the conditions from the `WHERE` clause up into each table's `ON` clause as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to error message you got, it is about Oracle, not MySQL.

Anyway, such a (classic?) principle should work: aggregate!

```
SQL>   with
  2  -- sample data
  3  movies (title_id, title_name) as
  4    (select 753595, '2F2F' from dual union all
  5     select 123456, '1Z1Z' from dual
  6    ),
  7  new_names (title_id, job_category, name) as
  8    (select 753595, 'writer', 'ROB' from dual union all
  9     select 753595, 'director', 'YAS' from dual
 10    )
 11  -- query you need
 12  select m.title_id,
 13    m.title_name,
 14    max(case when n.job_category = 'writer' then n.name end) as writer,
 15    max(case when n.job_category = 'director' then n.name end) as director
 16  from movies m left join new_names n on m.title_id = n.title_id
 17  group by m.title_id, m.title_name
 18  order by m.title_id;

  TITLE_ID TITL WRI DIR
---------- ---- --- ---
    123456 1Z1Z
    753595 2F2F ROB YAS

SQL>
```